# how to add back arrow in fragment for back action?

Tags: java, android, fragment

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:title="Profile"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

the code show the back arrow but how i can handle it on click on fragments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"` for back navigation like this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (ToolBar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

You should grab "view" variable like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, container, false);
```

Comment: its not working  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar

Comment: In your java code, you've imported the wrong Toolbar class. Just remove "android.widget.Toolbar" from your import and import Toolbar from "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"

Comment: getting this err java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: OK i got it. my bad. i just edited  my answer. put that code in your onCreateView() method in your fragment. and remember the "view" variable is the view that "inflater.inflate(...)" returns.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your java code?

Comment: here is my code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zY0gmuOFrwsoqF--MailOguaVg_WCyRn5kSJh9cCoN4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Replace "getActivity()" with "view" in this line -> "Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarProfile);"

Comment: why this error Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.cla.rltcfmcg.rest.RestCallback<java.util.ArrayList<com.cla.rltcfmcg.model.SubResponse>>', required: 'com.cla.rltcfmcg.rest.RestCallback<com.cla.rltcfmcg.model.SubResponse>'

Comment: That's another problem and it's not related to this one. You should search for answer or ask another question

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this to your onActivityCreated of your fragment

```
  getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

handle the click

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //What to do on back clicked
   }
});
```